# Fixing h1 font-size !important style size

Tags: html, css, styles, font-size

I have `font-size` in the `h1` tag with various sizes in many pages, but I wanted to standardize all of them to be `25px`, however when i tried to add a `style` in the `head` section of the page it didn't reflect the change at all.  How can I overwrite the original `font-size` with the needed one?

```css
h1 {font-size: 25px!important}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">
<span style="font-size: 10pt" lang="ar-sa">
<a style="text-decoration: none" href="example.come">
<font color="#008000">Title here</font></a></span></h1>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is an issue with the path, if your html same for the all title then you can use this type of path in your css

suggested css

h1 > span > a { font-size: 25px!important }

Comment: You did really great work. But please add enough explanation when you give a solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is taking the font size for your `h1` but as you have inline style for `span`. So you need to override `font-size` for not just to your `h1` but to `span`.

```css
h1 span {font-size: 25px!important}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">
<span style="font-size: 10pt" lang="ar-sa">
<a style="text-decoration: none" href="example.come">
<font color="#008000">Title here</font></a></span></h1>
```

Hope this answer helps you.